# How to access a model's attributes' data dynamically in an erb view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I want to show a list of items based on the order they are saved. For example, in my model (@gallery) I have a field called serializedmenu which contains the menu items in a particular order.

Now based on the menu item name I want to build a reference to the attribute that contains the actual data and display the data.

For example:

listname_for_video and listname_for_textbox are actual attributes of the model.

Using the code below, I loop through the menulist which only contains a part of the attribute name and I build the final reference to the attribute:

For this example, @menulist is an array that contains the names video and textbox.

```
<% @menulist = YAML::load(@gallery.serializedmenu) %>

<% @menulist.each do |menuitem| %>
<li>
  <a href="#<%=menuitem%>" >
  <%  myvar = "@gallery.listname_for_" +  menuitem %>
  <%= myvar %>  
  </a>
</li>
<% end %>
```

Unfortunately, this does not work since myvar just prints the string "@gallery.listname_for_video" and not the actual data.

Thanx for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, that was really easy. I should have searched more before I posted this question.
You can insert the keyword eval before the variable myvar

This will get you the actual data:

```
<% eval mvar %>
```